# Setting up Andrea USB Pod in Xubuntu

Tags: usb, audio

I'm not quite sure how to get the [Andrea USB pod](http://www.andreaelectronics.com/buy/ProductDesc/USB_Adapter.htm) to work in Xubuntu, and can't find much support for it online. Does anyone know how I can get it working?

Comment: could you plug it in and give the output of lsusb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Basically Pulseaudio (if Xubuntu comes with one) should detect it and display it as USB audio. If not, you may want to use [latest ALSA drivers](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page). But that's it. I don't think they support it, but it may worth a try. PulseAudio stopped releasing new versions for a while so thats a no go. (In my opinion, try Ubuntu livecd. If it not works, ask a XP license from a friend or something..everyone changed to W7 pretty much nowadays.)

Comment: Didnt work, but it's fine, I was just wondering. I dont think there is a clear cut solution other than writing my own driver.

Comment: Ehm. You should just leave the question then ^^" | Try Googleing about this thing in every few weeks.. someone may write a driver.